# Grav pages cannot be displayed under wordpress home folder

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, grav, amazon-lightsail

I created a wordpress vm using amazon-lightsail. The wordpress instance is accessible.

I moved a previous Grav installation under `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/doc` folder.

I am expecting to access the Grav using `https://MYDOMAIN/doc`. When I browse to `https://MYDOMAIN/doc`, a redirection to `https://MYDOMAIN/doc/tr` occurs. Then I see wordpress 404 page.

How can I access my grav pages?

Comment: Did you examine the `user/config/system.yaml` file to see if it fits your current configuration?

Comment: I didn't change any value in the yaml file. 

I downloaded a fresh grav zip and extracted it under wordpress home, but wordpress 404 page is displayed again. There seems to be a conflict with the bitnami's .htaccess file.

Comment: I updated `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` and changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Now, I can see grav content from `https://MYDOMAIN/doc/tr`.